# How to fit the Ringdroid waveform in full width according to width of mobile screen

Tags: android, mp3, waveform, ringdroid

I want to implement the **Ringdroid waveform** in my android app.But for some songs,the waveform created after choosing the song is larger than the screen size and for songs the waveform width is smaller than the mobile screen width .
Plz suggest me the change in code of Ringdroid ,so that every time the waveform of song **totally covers the width of screen**.

This is the link of Ringdroid project

https://github.com/google/ringdroid

Comment: did u find any solution??

Comment: no @DixitPatel .Do u have anything to implement this ?

Comment: @UditKumawat   were you able to solve this problem ??

Comment: @DixitPatel   were you able to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

After a whole lot of searching and surfing about it. I tried it myself and got the desired output with it

***This is the WaveformView class of Ringdroid***

```
package com.ringdroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

import com.ringdroid.soundfile.SoundFile;

/**
 * WaveformView is an Android view that displays a visual representation
 * of an audio waveform.  It retrieves the frame gains from a CheapSoundFile
 * object and recomputes the shape contour at several zoom levels.
 *
 * This class doesn't handle selection or any of the touch interactions
 * directly, so it exposes a listener interface.  The class that embeds
 * this view should add itself as a listener and make the view scroll
 * and respond to other events appropriately.
 *
 * WaveformView doesn't actually handle selection, but it will just display
 * the selected part of the waveform in a different color.
 */
public class WaveformView extends View {
    public interface WaveformListener {
        public void waveformTouchStart(float x);
        public void waveformTouchMove(float x);
        public void waveformTouchEnd();
        public void waveformFling(float x);
        public void waveformDraw();
        public void waveformZoomIn();
        public void waveformZoomOut();
    };

    // Colors
    private Paint mGridPaint;
    private Paint mSelectedLinePaint;
    private Paint mUnselectedLinePaint;
    private Paint mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint;
    private Paint mBorderLinePaint;
    private Paint mPlaybackLinePaint;
    private Paint mTimecodePaint;

    private SoundFile mSoundFile;
    private int[] mLenByZoomLevel;
    private double[][] mValuesByZoomLevel;
    private double[] mZoomFactorByZoomLevel;
    private int[] mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel;
    private int mZoomLevel;
    private int mNumZoomLevels;
    private int mSampleRate;
    private int mSamplesPerFrame;
    private int mOffset;
    private int mSelectionStart;
    private int mSelectionEnd;
    private int mPlaybackPos;
    private float mDensity;
    private float mInitialScaleSpan;
    private WaveformListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
    private boolean mInitialized;

    public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // We don't want keys, the markers get these
        setFocusable(false);

        Resources res = getResources();
        mGridPaint = new Paint();
        mGridPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mGridPaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.grid_line));
        mSelectedLinePaint = new Paint();
        mSelectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mSelectedLinePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.waveform_selected));
        mUnselectedLinePaint = new Paint();
        mUnselectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mUnselectedLinePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.waveform_unselected));
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint = new Paint();
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.waveform_unselected_bkgnd_overlay));
        mBorderLinePaint = new Paint();
        mBorderLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
        mBorderLinePaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 3.0f, 2.0f }, 0.0f));
        mBorderLinePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.selection_border));
        mPlaybackLinePaint = new Paint();
        mPlaybackLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mPlaybackLinePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.playback_indicator));
        mTimecodePaint = new Paint();
        mTimecodePaint.setTextSize(12);
        mTimecodePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTimecodePaint.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.timecode));
        mTimecodePaint.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, res.getColor(R.color.timecode_shadow));

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            context,
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vx, float vy) {
                    mListener.waveformFling(vx);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );

        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(
            context,
            new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
                public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector d) {
                    Log.v("Ringdroid", "ScaleBegin " + d.getCurrentSpanX());
                    mInitialScaleSpan = Math.abs(d.getCurrentSpanX());
                    return true;
                }
                public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector d) {
                    float scale = Math.abs(d.getCurrentSpanX());
                    Log.v("Ringdroid", "Scale " + (scale - mInitialScaleSpan));
                    if (scale - mInitialScaleSpan > 40) {
                        mListener.waveformZoomIn();
                        mInitialScaleSpan = scale;
                    }
                    if (scale - mInitialScaleSpan < -40) {
                        mListener.waveformZoomOut();
                        mInitialScaleSpan = scale;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector d) {
                    Log.v("Ringdroid", "ScaleEnd " + d.getCurrentSpanX());
                }
            }
        );

        mSoundFile = null;
        mLenByZoomLevel = null;
        mValuesByZoomLevel = null;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        mOffset = 0;
        mPlaybackPos = -1;
        mSelectionStart = 0;
        mSelectionEnd = 0;
        mDensity = 1.0f;
        mInitialized = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mListener.waveformTouchStart(event.getX());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mListener.waveformTouchMove(event.getX());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mListener.waveformTouchEnd();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasSoundFile() {
        return mSoundFile != null;
    }

    public void setSoundFile(SoundFile soundFile) {
        mSoundFile = soundFile;
        mSampleRate = mSoundFile.getSampleRate();
        mSamplesPerFrame = mSoundFile.getSamplesPerFrame();
        computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels();
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
    }

    public boolean isInitialized() {
        return mInitialized;
    }

    public int getZoomLevel() {
        return mZoomLevel;
    }

    public void setZoomLevel(int zoomLevel) {
        while (mZoomLevel > zoomLevel) {
            zoomIn();
        }
        while (mZoomLevel < zoomLevel) {
            zoomOut();
        }
    }

    public boolean canZoomIn() {
        return (mZoomLevel > 0);
    }

    public void zoomIn() {
        if (canZoomIn()) {
            mZoomLevel--;
            mSelectionStart *= 2;
            mSelectionEnd *= 2;
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
            int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            offsetCenter *= 2;
            mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            if (mOffset < 0)
                mOffset = 0;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public boolean canZoomOut() {
        return (mZoomLevel < mNumZoomLevels - 1);
    }

    public void zoomOut() {
        if (canZoomOut()) {
            mZoomLevel++;
            mSelectionStart /= 2;
            mSelectionEnd /= 2;
            int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            offsetCenter /= 2;
            mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            if (mOffset < 0)
                mOffset = 0;
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int maxPos() {
        return mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
    }

    public int secondsToFrames(double seconds) {
        return (int)(1.0 * seconds * mSampleRate / mSamplesPerFrame + 0.5);
    }

    public int secondsToPixels(double seconds) {
        double z = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
        return (int)(z * seconds * mSampleRate / mSamplesPerFrame + 0.5);
    }

    public double pixelsToSeconds(int pixels) {
        double z = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
        return (pixels * (double)mSamplesPerFrame / (mSampleRate * z));
    }

    public int millisecsToPixels(int msecs) {
        double z = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
        return (int)((msecs * 1.0 * mSampleRate * z) /
                     (1000.0 * mSamplesPerFrame) + 0.5);
    }

    public int pixelsToMillisecs(int pixels) {
        double z = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
        return (int)(pixels * (1000.0 * mSamplesPerFrame) /
                     (mSampleRate * z) + 0.5);
    }

    public void setParameters(int start, int end, int offset) {
        mSelectionStart = start;
        mSelectionEnd = end;
        mOffset = offset;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return mSelectionStart;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return mSelectionEnd;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return mOffset;
    }

    public void setPlayback(int pos) {
        mPlaybackPos = pos;
    }

    public void setListener(WaveformListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void recomputeHeights(float density) {
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        mDensity = density;
        mTimecodePaint.setTextSize((int)(12 * density));

        invalidate();
    }

    protected void drawWaveformLine(Canvas canvas,
                                    int x, int y0, int y1,
                                    Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y0, x, y1, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mSoundFile == null)
            return;

        if (mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel == null)
            computeIntsForThisZoomLevel();

        // Draw waveform
        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int start = mOffset;
        int width = mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length - start;
        int ctr = measuredHeight / 2;

        if (width > measuredWidth)
            width = measuredWidth;

        // Draw grid
        double onePixelInSecs = pixelsToSeconds(1);
        boolean onlyEveryFiveSecs = (onePixelInSecs > 1.0 / 50.0);
        double fractionalSecs = mOffset * onePixelInSecs;
        int integerSecs = (int) fractionalSecs;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < width) {
            i++;
            fractionalSecs += onePixelInSecs;
            int integerSecsNew = (int) fractionalSecs;
            if (integerSecsNew != integerSecs) {
                integerSecs = integerSecsNew;
                if (!onlyEveryFiveSecs || 0 == (integerSecs % 5)) {
                    canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mGridPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw waveform
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Paint paint;
            if (i + start >= mSelectionStart &&
                i + start < mSelectionEnd) {
                paint = mSelectedLinePaint;
            } else {
                drawWaveformLine(canvas, i, 0, measuredHeight,
                                 mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
                paint = mUnselectedLinePaint;
            }
            drawWaveformLine(
                canvas, i,
                ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                paint);

            if (i + start == mPlaybackPos) {
                canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mPlaybackLinePaint);
            }
        }

        // If we can see the right edge of the waveform, draw the
        // non-waveform area to the right as unselected
        for (i = width; i < measuredWidth; i++) {
            drawWaveformLine(canvas, i, 0, measuredHeight,
                             mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
        }

        // Draw borders
        canvas.drawLine(
            mSelectionStart - mOffset + 0.5f, 30,
            mSelectionStart - mOffset + 0.5f, measuredHeight,
            mBorderLinePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(
            mSelectionEnd - mOffset + 0.5f, 0,
            mSelectionEnd - mOffset + 0.5f, measuredHeight - 30,
            mBorderLinePaint);

        // Draw timecode
        double timecodeIntervalSecs = 1.0;
        if (timecodeIntervalSecs / onePixelInSecs < 50) {
            timecodeIntervalSecs = 5.0;
        }
        if (timecodeIntervalSecs / onePixelInSecs < 50) {
            timecodeIntervalSecs = 15.0;
        }

        // Draw grid
        fractionalSecs = mOffset * onePixelInSecs;
        int integerTimecode = (int) (fractionalSecs / timecodeIntervalSecs);
        i = 0;
        while (i < width) {
            i++;
            fractionalSecs += onePixelInSecs;
            integerSecs = (int) fractionalSecs;
            int integerTimecodeNew = (int) (fractionalSecs /
                                            timecodeIntervalSecs);
            if (integerTimecodeNew != integerTimecode) {
                integerTimecode = integerTimecodeNew;

                // Turn, e.g. 67 seconds into "1:07"
                String timecodeMinutes = "" + (integerSecs / 60);
                String timecodeSeconds = "" + (integerSecs % 60);
                if ((integerSecs % 60) < 10) {
                    timecodeSeconds = "0" + timecodeSeconds;
                }
                String timecodeStr = timecodeMinutes + ":" + timecodeSeconds;
                float offset = (float) (
                    0.5 * mTimecodePaint.measureText(timecodeStr));
                canvas.drawText(timecodeStr,
                                i - offset,
                                (int)(12 * mDensity),
                                mTimecodePaint);
            }
        }

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.waveformDraw();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called once when a new sound file is added
     */
    private void computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels() {
        int numFrames = mSoundFile.getNumFrames();
        int[] frameGains = mSoundFile.getFrameGains();
        double[] smoothedGains = new double[numFrames];
        if (numFrames == 1) {
            smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
        } else if (numFrames == 2) {
            smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
            smoothedGains[1] = frameGains[1];
        } else if (numFrames > 2) {
            smoothedGains[0] = (double)(
                (frameGains[0] / 2.0) +
                (frameGains[1] / 2.0));
            for (int i = 1; i < numFrames - 1; i++) {
                smoothedGains[i] = (double)(
                    (frameGains[i - 1] / 3.0) +
                    (frameGains[i    ] / 3.0) +
                    (frameGains[i + 1] / 3.0));
            }
            smoothedGains[numFrames - 1] = (double)(
                (frameGains[numFrames - 2] / 2.0) +
                (frameGains[numFrames - 1] / 2.0));
        }

        // Make sure the range is no more than 0 - 255
        double maxGain = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            if (smoothedGains[i] > maxGain) {
                maxGain = smoothedGains[i];
            }
        }
        double scaleFactor = 1.0;
        if (maxGain > 255.0) {
            scaleFactor = 255 / maxGain;
        }

        // Build histogram of 256 bins and figure out the new scaled max
        maxGain = 0;
        int gainHist[] = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            int smoothedGain = (int)(smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor);
            if (smoothedGain < 0)
                smoothedGain = 0;
            if (smoothedGain > 255)
                smoothedGain = 255;

            if (smoothedGain > maxGain)
                maxGain = smoothedGain;

            gainHist[smoothedGain]++;
        }

        // Re-calibrate the min to be 5%
        double minGain = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (minGain < 255 && sum < numFrames / 20) {
            sum += gainHist[(int)minGain];
            minGain++;
        }

        // Re-calibrate the max to be 99%
        sum = 0;
        while (maxGain > 2 && sum < numFrames / 100) {
            sum += gainHist[(int)maxGain];
            maxGain--;
        }

        // Compute the heights
        double[] heights = new double[numFrames];
        double range = maxGain - minGain;
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            double value = (smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor - minGain) / range;
            if (value < 0.0)
                value = 0.0;
            if (value > 1.0)
                value = 1.0;
            heights[i] = value * value;
        }

        mNumZoomLevels = 5;
        mLenByZoomLevel = new int[5];
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel = new double[5];
        mValuesByZoomLevel = new double[5][];

        // Level 0 is doubled, with interpolated values
        mLenByZoomLevel[0] = numFrames * 2;
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[0] = 2.0;
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[0]];
        if (numFrames > 0) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][0] = 0.5 * heights[0];
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][1] = heights[0];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < numFrames; i++) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i] = 0.5 * (heights[i - 1] + heights[i]);
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i + 1] = heights[i];
        }

        // Level 1 is normal
        mLenByZoomLevel[1] = numFrames;
        mValuesByZoomLevel[1] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[1]];
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[1] = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[1]; i++) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[1][i] = heights[i];
        }

        // 3 more levels are each halved
        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
            mLenByZoomLevel[j] = mLenByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2;
            mValuesByZoomLevel[j] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[j]];
            mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j] = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[j]; i++) {
                mValuesByZoomLevel[j][i] =
                    0.5 * (mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i] +
                           mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i + 1]);
            }
        }

        if (numFrames > 5000) {
            mZoomLevel = 3;
        } else if (numFrames > 1000) {
            mZoomLevel = 2;
        } else if (numFrames > 300) {
            mZoomLevel = 1;
        } else {
            mZoomLevel = 0;
        }

        mInitialized = true;
    }

    /**
     * Called the first time we need to draw when the zoom level has changed
     * or the screen is resized
     */
    private void computeIntsForThisZoomLevel() {
        int halfHeight = (getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - 1;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = new int[mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]];
        for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]; i++) {
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[i] =
                (int)(mValuesByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel][i] * halfHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

***The change is here in this part of code***

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 int ScreenWidth= displaymetrics.widthPixels;




// Draw waveform
        for ( i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Paint paint;

            if (i + start >= mSelectionStart &&
                    i + start < mSelectionEnd) {
                paint = mSelectedLinePaint;
            } else {
                drawWaveformLine(canvas, ((ScreenWidth/width)*i), 0, measuredHeight,
                        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
                paint = mUnselectedLinePaint;
            }
            drawWaveformLine(
                    canvas, ((ScreenWidth/width)*i),
                    ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    paint);
```

**you have to change the x-axis of draw line method according to your screen size**

Comment: Ringdroid waveform is scrolling

Comment: small waveform unable width according to width of mobile screen

Comment: This solution is working only to display the full screen waveform. but when we are trying to play the song, the displayed waveform is not syncing with the maxPos which is calculated from the zoolLevels. How could you sync that, can you please help on this?

Comment: If my audio is 3 second and i want to set waveform into full width screen, can you help me

Comment: Waveform is still scrolling. Can you please add your drawLine code

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan have you found solution because by above solution it is still scolling

Comment: has anyone found solution as by above solution it is still scolling

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * A view that displays audio data on the screen as a waveform.
 */
public class WaveformView extends SurfaceView {

  // The number of buffer frames to keep around (for a nice fade-out
  // visualization.
  private static final int HISTORY_SIZE = 6;

  // To make quieter sounds still show up well on the display, we use
  // +/- 8192 as the amplitude that reaches the top/bottom of the view
  // instead of +/- 32767. Any samples that have magnitude higher than this
  // limit will simply be clipped during drawing.
  private static final float MAX_AMPLITUDE_TO_DRAW = 8192.0f;

  // The queue that will hold historical audio data.
  private LinkedList<short[]> mAudioData;
  private Paint mPaint;

  public WaveformView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
  }

  public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mAudioData = new LinkedList<short[]>();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  }

  /**
   * Updates the waveform view with a new "frame" of samples and renders it.
   * The new frame gets added to the front of the rendering queue, pushing the
   * previous frames back, causing them to be faded out visually.
   * 
   * @param buffer the most recent buffer of audio samples.
   */
  public synchronized void updateAudioData(short[] buffer) {
    short[] newBuffer;

    // We want to keep a small amount of history in the view to provide a nice
    // fading effect. We use a linked list that we treat as a queue for this.
    if (mAudioData.size() == HISTORY_SIZE) {
      newBuffer = mAudioData.removeFirst();
      System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, buffer.length);
    } else {
      newBuffer = buffer.clone();
    }

    mAudioData.addLast(newBuffer);

    // Update the display.
    Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    if (canvas != null) {
      drawWaveform(canvas);
      getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Repaints the view's surface.
   * 
   * @param canvas the {@link Canvas} object on which to draw.
   */
  private void drawWaveform(Canvas canvas) {
    // Clear the screen each time because SurfaceView won't do this for us.
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();
    float centerY = height / 2;

    // We draw the history from oldest to newest so that the older audio
    // data is further back and darker than the most recent data.
    int colorDelta = 255 / (HISTORY_SIZE + 1);
    int brightness = colorDelta;

    for (short[] buffer : mAudioData) {
      mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(brightness, 128, 255, 192));

      float lastX = -1;
      float lastY = -1;

      // For efficiency, we don't draw all of the samples in the buffer,
      // but only the ones that align with pixel boundaries.
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int index = (int) ((x / width) * buffer.length);
        short sample = buffer[index];
        float y = (sample / MAX_AMPLITUDE_TO_DRAW) * centerY + centerY;

        if (lastX != -1) {
          canvas.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y, mPaint);
        }

        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
      }

      brightness += colorDelta;
    }
  }
}
```